# QGIS: How do I clip away rivers extending beyond my state shapefile?

Tags: clip, boundaries

Re-learning QGIS after a four-year hiatus. I'm trying to make a basic map of the state of Nebraska, complete with county boundaries and a river-system shapefile. I have both shapefiles present in the layers and all is well except the rivers extend beyond the boundary of the state. How can I cut away the rivers laying outside of the state-boundary.

[image: Nebraska and River shapefiles]

Comment: Please have a look at other questions here, you may find that your questions has been asked and answered many times. Try seraching for "clipping"

Answer (score 0):

1. [Explode lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines) on the rivers layer.
2. [Select by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location): Select features from rivers layer > disjoint > by comparing to the features from county layer.
3. Delete selected features.
4. [Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate) the remaining lines, based on a common attribute of the initial river lines like id or name.